# scala count strings in a list contained in a read file

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, immutability

I am new to SO but have spent days going through related to questions. The closest related question I found is [How to compare each word of a line in a file with a list element in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285670/how-to-compare-each-word-of-a-line-in-a-file-with-a-list-element-in-scala) but that goes back to 2014 so thought there may be different solutions now.

Also in the above quoted post the best answer uses a mutable data struct which I am trying to avoid. The last answer by Dima looked more functional however did not work :(

I am trying to create a similar program in SCALA except the output should also contain an overall count for the keyword and all keywords should be outputed, even if no matches were found, thus the count would be zero.

The keywords to check against are hard coded into a list however I also want to add the option of a 2nd user supplied argument that contains the keywords. So far I have come to the following but got suck:

```
object FileAnalyser extends App {

val hardcodedkeywords = List("foo", "bar", "hello")

if (args.length > 1) {
  val keywords = args(1).toList
  try {
    val rdd = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines.toList.zipWithIndex.flatMap {
      case(line, index) => line.split("\\W+").map { (_, index+1) }
    } //.filter(keywords.contains(_)).groupBy { _._1 }.mapValues(_._2)
  } catch {
    case ioe: IOException => println(ioe)
    case fnf: FileNotFoundException => println(fnf)
    case _: Throwable => println("Uknown error occured")
  }
} else 
  try {
    val rdd = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines.toList.zipWithIndex.flatMap {
      case(line, index) => line.split("\\W+").map { (_, index+1) }
    } //filter(hardcodedkeywords.contains(_))
      //.groupBy { _._1 }.mapValues(_._2)
  } catch {
    case ioe: IOException => println(ioe)
    case fnf: FileNotFoundException => println(fnf)
    case _: Throwable => println("Uknown error occured")
  }
}
```

So far I have managed to use args(0) containing the file to read, to be read, and mapped to a list containing a string per line as well index+1 (as line numbers start from 1 but index starts from 0)
The program must be as functional as possible so less mutables and state changes and more higher order functions and list recursions.

Thanks
Example output would be:

```
//alphabetical      //No duplicates
//order             //Increasing in no. 
keyword              lines                count
bar                  [1,2..]                6
foo                  [3,5]                  2
hello                []                     0
```

Comment: Can you add an example output? We don't need to see the file contents, just an example of keyword data formatted as you'd like it returned (or printed).

Comment: Hi I have just done this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic outline to how it might be done.

```
val keywords = List(/*key words here*/)

val resMap = io.Source
  .fromFile(/*file to read*/)
  .getLines()
  .zipWithIndex
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String,Seq[Int]].withDefaultValue(Seq.empty[Int])){
    case (m, (line, idx)) =>
      val subMap = line.split("\\W+").toSeq  //separate the words
        .filter(keywords.contains)           //keep only key words
        .groupBy(identity)                   //make a Map w/ keyword as key
        .mapValues(_.map(_ => idx+1))        //and List of line numbers as value
        .withDefaultValue(Seq.empty[Int])
      keywords.map(kw => (kw, m(kw) ++ subMap(kw))).toMap
  }

//formatted results (needs work)
println("keyword\t\tlines\t\tcount")
keywords.sorted.foreach{kw =>
  println(kw + "\t\t" +
          resMap(kw).distinct.mkString("[",",","]") + "\t\t" +
          resMap(kw).length
         )
}
```

---

***some explanation***

- `io.Source` is the library (actually an `object`) that offers some basic input/output methods, including `fromFile()`, which opens a file for reading.
- `getLines()` reads from the file one line at a time.
- `zipWithIndex` attaches an index value to each line read.
- `foldLeft()` reads all the lines of the file, one at a time, and (in this case) builds a `Map` of all the key words and their line locations.
- `resMap` and `subMap` are just the names I chose to give to the variables I'm building. `resMap` (result Map) is what's created after the whole file has been processed. `subMap` is an intermediate Map built from just one line of text from the file.

If you want the option of passing in a collection of key words, I'd do it like this:

```
val keywords = if (args.length > 1) args.tail.toList else hardcodedkeywords
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind sharing an explanation of your code? I have never seen some stuff before like io.source (used to source.getfiles), resmap, submap etc so your solution is alien to me. Also from what I can tell if I want keywords to not be hardcoded and supplied as second argument would I wrap your solution in an if statement like in my OP?

Comment: im really sorry I just realised right after sending my comment that resmap and submap are val names. Too late/early in the night/morning for me lol. Are most of the functions youre using higher order funcs like getlines, zipwithindex etc. And from what I can see your solution is very functional as theres no vars and from what I can see no mutability side affects and state changes as theres no mutability. But if I wanted to make it more functional, is that even possibele? or would I just be finding an alternate solution. I want to try make one as optimum as poss in terms of bigO

Comment: Everything presented here is out of the Standard Library. Some (not all) of these methods do qualify as "higher order". You're right, no `var`s, side effects, or mutable state. More functional? Probably: if you were to delve into an advanced library such as Shapeless or Cats. Some minor efficiency gains might be achieved by rearranging the order of some methods and moving some processing from inside the `foldLeft()`. (I put this together rather quickly.)

Comment: Thank you. A final curiosity I have, the solution (which is correct to what I asked for) would be limited to 22 keywords as that is the max size of a tuple. How would you implement this in a case where more than 22 keywords are required?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. There are no tuples or keyword limits in the above code. (Well, `zipWithIndex` creates an `Iterator[Tuple2[String,Int]]` but that has nothing to do with the keyword `List`.) This should work for 23 keywords or 23,000 keywords.

Comment: Hi,When I was messing around on scala i saw when creating a list it would produce an error if there were more than 22 elements. When running your code with >22 elements in the hardcodedkeywords list it doesnt give an error for some reason.

Comment: BTW when trying to put symbols in the hardcodedkeywords like "@", "#" and "=>" to check if the file contains them, the output is always 0 count and obviously 0 line numbers even when I purposely put those symbols in the read file. Apparently I have to use the stringEscapeUtils?

Comment: 1 - It's entirely possible to create a `List` of >22 elements. You might want to post your code as a new question. 2 - You can't count symbols because you're splitting the `String` on non-word `\W+` characters, which includes spaces as well as the those symbols. You can't count something that's been removed from the data. You could change it to split on just spaces `\s+` but then something like `me@home` will be 1 word and not included in the count of keywords `me` or `home` or `@`. 3 - Is my answer good enough to be "accepted"?

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Would you be able to PM me? When I click "move this discussion to a chat" it wont let me as I am too new to SO. I want to show you my code and perhaps a few more questions...

Comment: I'm surprised it hasn't asked me to "move this discussion". Oh well. I've create a [Scala chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188849/scala-chat) room. Let's see if that works.

Comment: ah im sorry but SO will not let me talk on the chat as I have less than 20 reps. My code currently is:

Comment: val hardcodedkeywords = List("abstract", "case","=", "=>", "<-",
                  "<:", "<%", ">:", "#", "@"//,...)
                  
 val keywords = if (args.length > 1) args.toList.drop(1) else 
    hardcodedkeywords
 
 val resMap = io.Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines().zipWithIndex
     .foldLeft(Map.empty[String,Seq[Int]].withDefaultValue(Seq.empty[Int])){
      case (m, (line, idx)) =>
       val subMap = line.split("\\W+").toSeq  //separate the words
        .filter(keywords.contains)           //keep only key words

Comment: .groupBy(identity)                   //make a Map w/ keyword as key
        .mapValues(_.map(_ => idx+1))        //and List of line numbers as value
        .withDefaultValue(Seq.empty[Int])
      keywords.map(kw => (kw, m(kw) ++ subMap(kw))).toMap
      }

     //formatted results (needs work)
     println("Keyword\t\tLine Numbers\t\tCount")
     keywords.sorted.foreach{kw =>
     println(kw + "\t\t" +
          resMap(kw).distinct.mkString("[",",","]") + "\t\t" +
          resMap(kw).length
         )
        }

Comment: I'm able to make it work by changing the splitting targets: `split("""[,"\s]+""")` You might not need the quote `"` in the character class (the part between `[` and `]`). I needed it for my test data. If you don't need to spit on quotes then `split("[,\\s]+")` should be sufficient.

Comment: Problem here is that it won't find `<:` inside of `A<:B` because there are no spaces to split on. You might drop the splitting approach but then there's the problem of counting `=` separate from `=>`. Not a trivial task.